# Why does my Binary search tree crash when I delete a Node that doesn't exist in the tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

The program crashes when I run the main method. I tried to delete "Nike" which doesn't exist from the tree. However in the first while loop inside the delete method, when the child variable is null, the method stops executing. When while loop can't find any value that matches the element, the child variable will run to null, and the method will be "return", which is the same as ended. But, why doesn't my while loop works as I expected?

```
          public class Node
         {
           String value;
           Node leftChild;
           Node rightChild;

           Node(String val,Node left, Node right)
             {
             value = val;
             leftChild = left;
             rightChild = right;
             }

           Node(String val)
           {
           value = val;
           leftChild = null;
           rightChild = null;

           }
       }



      public class binarySearchTree
     {
        Node root;

        binarySearchTree()
        {
        root = null;
        }
       private Node insert(String element, Node bstree)
       {  

       if(root == null)
       {
       root = new Node(element);
       return root;
       }

      if(bstree == null)
      {
      return new Node(element);
      }

     else if(element.compareTo(bstree.value) < 0)
     {
     bstree.leftChild = insert(element,bstree.leftChild);
     }
     else
    {
    bstree.rightChild = insert(element,bstree.rightChild);
    }

   return bstree;
}

 public boolean insert(String element)
{
   insert(element,root);
   return true;
}

 public void delete(String element)
{


    if(root == null)
   {
    System.out.print("Tree is empty");
    return;
   }



   Node child = root;
   Node parent = root;
   while(element.compareTo(child.value) != 0)
   {
      if(child == null)
      {
      System.out.println("Element not found.");
      return;
      }
     else if(element.compareTo(child.value) < 0)
     {
     parent = child;
     child = child.leftChild;
     }
     else 
    {
     parent = child;
     child = child.rightChild;
    }
}

     //if the Node being deleted is the root
     if(child == root)
    {
     if(child.leftChild == null&&child.rightChild == null)
     root = null;
     else if(child.leftChild != null && child.rightChild == null)
     root = root.leftChild;
     else if(child.rightChild != null && child.leftChild == null)
     root = root.rightChild;

     }

    //case 1;
   if(child.leftChild == null&&child.rightChild == null)
   {
      if(parent.leftChild == child)
         parent.leftChild = null;

     else if(parent.rightChild == child)
        parent.rightChild = null;
   }

   //case 2
   if(child.leftChild != null && child.rightChild == null)
   {
      if(parent.leftChild == child)
         parent.leftChild = child.leftChild;

       else if(parent.rightChild == child)
         parent.rightChild = child.leftChild;
   }


   if(child.rightChild != null && child.leftChild == null)
   {
     if(parent.leftChild == child)
        parent.leftChild = child.rightChild;

     else if(parent.rightChild == child)
       parent.rightChild = child.rightChild;
   }


   //case 3
if(child.leftChild != null && child.rightChild != null)
   {
     Node rightMost = child.leftChild;
     Node newLeaf = child;

    if(rightMost.rightChild == null)
    {
      child.value = rightMost.value;
      child.leftChild = null;
    }

    else
    {
    while(rightMost.rightChild != null)
    {
      newLeaf = rightMost;
      rightMost = rightMost.rightChild;
    }

    //swap value
    child.value = rightMost.value;
    newLeaf.rightChild = null;
   }

 }


   class testing
    {
     public static void main(String[] agrs)
      {
      binarySearchTree tree = new binarySearchTree();
      System.out.print("This is the original binary search tree: \n");
      tree.insert("taco");
      tree.insert("banana");
      tree.insert("kiwi");
      tree.insert("pineapple");
      tree.insert("strawberry");
      tree.insert("cookie");
      tree.insert("mango");
      tree.insert("coke");



      tree.delete("coke");
      tree.delete("mango");
      tree.delete("Nike");




 }

}
```

Comment: Please format this properly if you expect anybody to read it.

Comment: good now? I just changed the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your code references `child.value` before checking to see if `child` is null. You have this loop:

```
while(element.compareTo(child.value) != 0)
{
    if(child == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Element not found.");
        return;
    }
    else if(element.compareTo(child.value) < 0)
    {
        parent = child;
        child = child.leftChild;
    }
    else 
    {
        parent = child;
        child = child.rightChild;
    }
}
```

The first time through the loop, `child` is equal to `root`, and you know that `root` is not null. But if the comparison fails you assign a new child, either `child = child.rightChild` or `child = child.leftChild`. Then you do the comparison again, without checking to see if `child` is null. If `child` is null, then attempting to reference `child.value` throws an exception.

The easiest way to fix that is:

```
while (child != null && element.compareTo(child.value) != 0)
{
    // do stuff here
}
// moved from inside the loop
if(child == null)
{
    System.out.println("Element not found.");
    return;
}
```